# Remove certain special HTML characters from string in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, xpath, character

I am scraping information from a website and I was wondering how could I ignore or replace some special HTML characters such as "`&aacute;`", "`&aacute;`", "`&rsquo;`" and "`&amp"`. These characters cannot be scraped into a database. I have already replaced "`&nbsp;`" using this:

```
$nbsp = utf8_decode('Ã¡');
$mystring = str_replace($nbsp, '', $mystring);
```

But I cannot seem to do the same with these other characters. I am scraping from the website using XPath. This returns the exact content that I am looking for but keeps the HTML characters that I do not want as they don't seem to be allowed into a database.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: XY problem. Those characters are perfectly fine in a database. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Not in mine. I have even replaced these characters with what they are meant to represent and that inserted no problem, yet when I leave them in it won't insert.

Comment: Soooooooooooo you are not in the least wondering why it doesn't get added to your database and instead you want to sweep the problem under the carpet? Pro tip: the chances of this ending well are slim.

Comment: @PeeHaa is correct, but have you looked at [html_entity_decode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)? (In case you have a more logical reason to want to do this...)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a collation issue. I suggest ensuring that your database collation is set to utf8_ci, and that your web page's content encoding is also set to UTF-8. This may well solve your problem.

---

The best way to strip all special characters is to run the string through `htmlspecialchars()`, then do a case-insensitive regex find and replace using the following pattern:

```
&([a-z]{2,8}+|#[0-9]{2,5}|#x[0-9a-f]{2,4});
```

This should match named HTML entities (e.g. `&ohm;` or `&nbsp;`) as well as decimal (e.g. `&#01234`) and hex-based (e.g. `&x0BEE;`) entities. The regex will strip them out completely.

Alternatively, just use the output of `htmlspecialchars()` to store it with the weird characters intact. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Turns out this preg_replace suits my needs: preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);